# How do loop through nested json object with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Struggling with iterating through the following return json string from an API:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "ActionNeeded": null,
  "OldestStatus": null,
  "ServiceHost": "W501",
  "ServiceName": "Renewals",
  "ServiceStatusDateTime": "2023-03-15T22:47:05.313000",
  "ServiceVersion": "1.0.0",
  "SortOrder": "0",
  "TimeAgo": null
},
{
  "ActionNeeded": null,
  "OldestStatus": null,
  "ServiceHost": "W202",
  "ServiceName": "Monitor",
  "ServiceStatusDateTime": "2023-03-15T22:46:42.560000",
  "ServiceVersion": null,
  "SortOrder": "1",
  "TimeAgo": null
},
{
  "ActionNeeded": null,
  "OldestStatus": null,
  "ServiceHost": "W0070204",
  "ServiceName": "Monitor",
  "ServiceStatusDateTime": "2023-03-15T22:46:39.840000",
  "ServiceVersion": "2.0.2",
  "SortOrder": "1",
  "TimeAgo": null
}
]
]
```

I've tried a for..in loop, but am only managing to get the first "set" of key/value pairs.

Here is my current code:

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse(event.data);

// Returned records
const items = json_obj['data'];

for (var item_index in items) {
    if (items.hasOwnProperty(item_index)) {
        console.log(item_index);
    }
}
```

How can I loop through each "set" of data and out both key and value?

Comment: So you want to loop over all the objects in that array? Or do you want to go through all objects recursively?

Comment: Would like to loop through each index in that "data" object (each set of { }) and be able to reference each key/value set (at a time if possible). Like.. data[0] = {"ActionNeeded": null, "OldestStatus": null}, data[1] = etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#forEach` or `for...of` to loop over an array and `Object.entries` to get all the key-value pairs in an object.

```js
let o={data:[{ActionNeeded:null,OldestStatus:null,ServiceHost:"W501",ServiceName:"Renewals",ServiceStatusDateTime:"2023-03-15T22:47:05.313000",ServiceVersion:"1.0.0",SortOrder:"0",TimeAgo:null},{ActionNeeded:null,OldestStatus:null,ServiceHost:"W202",ServiceName:"Monitor",ServiceStatusDateTime:"2023-03-15T22:46:42.560000",ServiceVersion:null,SortOrder:"1",TimeAgo:null},{ActionNeeded:null,OldestStatus:null,ServiceHost:"W0070204",ServiceName:"Monitor",ServiceStatusDateTime:"2023-03-15T22:46:39.840000",ServiceVersion:"2.0.2",SortOrder:"1",TimeAgo:null}]};
o.data.forEach((x, i) => {
  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(x)) 
    console.log('index', i, k, '=', v);
});
```

Comment: Let me try this out! I've been so used to jquery's .each stuff, that I'm struggling with vanilla methods for this.. embarrassing lol

Comment: So this works in a way. So it seems like it goes through every item, and for each item, outputs each key/value pair. Is there a way I can reference a key directly for each "item" instead of looping over every key? That way I can do something like: "for each item, if 'ActionNeeded' != '' then print the ServiceName"

Comment: @SourceMatters It depends. If you have a string, you need JSON.parse to parse it. If you already have an object, then you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is good approach, hope this work for you!

```
const eventJsonString = JSON.stringify({
    "data": [
        {
            "ActionNeeded": null,
            "OldestStatus": null,
            "ServiceHost": "W501",
            "ServiceName": "Renewals",
            "ServiceStatusDateTime": "2023-03-15T22:47:05.313000",
            "ServiceVersion": "1.0.0",
            "SortOrder": "0",
            "TimeAgo": null
        },
        {
            "ActionNeeded": null,
            "OldestStatus": null,
            "ServiceHost": "W202",
            "ServiceName": "Monitor",
            "ServiceStatusDateTime": "2023-03-15T22:46:42.560000",
            "ServiceVersion": null,
            "SortOrder": "1",
            "TimeAgo": null
        },
        {
            "ActionNeeded": null,
            "OldestStatus": null,
            "ServiceHost": "W0070204",
            "ServiceName": "Monitor",
            "ServiceStatusDateTime": "2023-03-15T22:46:39.840000",
            "ServiceVersion": "2.0.2",
            "SortOrder": "1",
            "TimeAgo": null
        }
    ]
});

const event = JSON.parse(eventJsonString);
const items = event.data;

items.forEach(item => {
    const { ActionNeeded, OldestStatus, ServiceHost, ServiceName,
        ServiceStatusDateTime, ServiceVersion, SortOrder, TimeAgo } = item;

    console.log(ActionNeeded);
    console.log(OldestStatus);
    console.log(ServiceHost);
    console.log(ServiceName);
    console.log(ServiceStatusDateTime);
    console.log(ServiceVersion);
    console.log(SortOrder);
    console.log(TimeAgo);
    console.log("---------------");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snipper `items` is an array, but you are using `for...in` which is meant for objects. You can change it to `for...of` and you won't need `hasOwnProperty` anymore since it's meant for keys in an object:

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse(event.data);

// Returned records
const items = json_obj['data'];

for (var item of items) {
    console.log(item);
}
```